# Is every Borel set finitely decomposable into open sets?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Given a topological space $\langle X, T \rangle $, consider the Borel algebra $B$ generated by $T$. The question is, can you write any $b \in B$ using only finitely many open (or closed) sets using set operations $\cup$ and $\sim$ (and $\cap$) ?

For closed and open sets, this is obviously the case. So the characterization is only interesting for sets which are neither open nor closed.

For example, consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and the following set: $$A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

$A$ is a Borel set and obviously, $A$ is neither open nor closed. But $A' = A \cup \{ 0 \}$ is closed and one can rewrite $A$ as $A' \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Since both sets are closed, $A$ is "finitely decomposable into open (or closed) sets."

If not, can you give a counter example?

Comment: it is very far from that. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy for a description of the hierarchy of Borel sets.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary proof that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ can not be constructed as you describe.

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.  We will prove that all sets $A$ generated in the way you describe have the following property (let's call it property **P**):

**Property P:** For any open interval $I$, either $I \cap A$ or $I - A$ contains an open interval.

This is clearly true of closed and open sets: Either $I \cap A$ or $I - A$ is open, thus either contains an open interval or is empty, but if $I \cap A$ is empty, $I - A = I$ and vice versa.

Thus we need only show this property is preserved under complements and finite unions.  Complements are clear, since they merely switch $I \cap A$ and $I - A$.

So we now need only show that if $A_1,A_2 \subset R$ have property $P$, then so does $A_1 \cup A_2$.  So fix an $I$.  Clearly if $I \cap A_1$ or $I \cap A_2$ contains an open interval then we're done, so we can assume $I - A_1 $ and $I - A_2$ both contain open subintervals of $I$, call them $I_1$ and $I_2$, respectively.

By property $P$, either $I_1 \cap A_2$ or $I_1 - A_2$ contains an open interval $I'$.  If the former, then $I' \subset I \cap (A_1 \cup A_2)$.  If the latter, then $I'$ is disjoint from both $A_1$ and $A_2$, thus $I' \subset I - (A_1 \cup A_2)$.  This shows that $A_1 \cup A_2$ has property **P**.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with dense complement, it clearly does not satisfy property $P$.  But it is Borel (as it is a countable union of closed points), and thus is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My follow up question is, do you have any reference for the proposition that "finitely decomposable sets" have the property P? On the net or not doesn't matter...

Comment: No, I just came up with this property as a way to prove the statement (though I'm sure others have come up with it before me).  Is there something wrong with the proof I provided that finitely decomposable sets have this property?

Comment: When you formulate property P, I think you meant $I \cap A$ and not $I \cup A$, right? This mix-up seem to continue in the rest of the proof as well, or I am missing something?

Comment: Oh man, no wonder it was causing confusion!  Thanks for figuring that out; I've corrected it to use $I \cap A$.

Comment: Okay, one final (hopefully) question. I'm now looking into a "practical" characterisation of these finitely decomposable sets (FDS). How about the claim that sets x such that int(x) = int (Cl(x)) and Cl(x)=Cl(int(x)) are always FDS?

Comment: Also, if you have a another characterisation in mind, I'll take that too ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to use a Borel algebra which contains only FDS by simply removing sets from it that are not FDS. But I want to first understand what kind of sets I am removing and whats left is still useful...

Comment: You mean you're removing the open sets from the topology?  Otherwise in order to have a Borel algebra you'll have to keep all countable sets, which will be a problem in, say, $\mathbb{R}$. The only way I could see making it work is if your underlying set it finite, or your topology is extremely course. Also, Cl(x)=Cl(int(x)) seems untrue of many FDS's; finite sets in \mathbb{R} which have empty interior, for example.

Comment: No, that is not what I meant but I can see that my description was completely misleading. The outcome need not be a Borel algebra anymore after I remove non-FDSs. I can live with a non-Borel subset of a Borel algebra. As to the regularity conditions I mentioned, if not a full characterisation, then they could still be useful as sufficient conditions to me. But I have no idea how to come up with a proof.

Comment: Why don't you ask this as a separate question?